# (Scala) Get index of current yield iteration with a loop?

Tags: scala, for-loop, indexing

i came across this problem that i have no idea how to resolve... I have a square shaped text. For example like this:

```
x xxxx
xxx xx
x xxxx
xx xxx
```

I want to get each horizontal line and vertical line and assign coordinates to their start positions starting from top to bottom left to right(where top left corner is (0;0)). Seems easy, however, in Scala when i use a for loop in my code i don't have current iterations index (like foreach doesn't have index in c#). These kind of errors get me stuck during functional programming process(I come from OOP background, so, you know:) it's kind of frustrating at times..)

```
val verticalWords = for(i <- verticalData) yield {



    //<---------- Here is where i need to know current iterations index.
    //If i had current index i could easily set get coordinates by indexes.
    //How do i get current index here?



    val currentWords = i.split(" ").filter(_.length > 0)
    val objWords = for(c <- currentWords) yield {
        Word(Orientation.VERTICAL, c.toString)
    }

    objWords //Array of words
}
```

-Thank you so much!!

Comment: What is `verticalData`? Also, there's nothing wrong with traditional `for(i <- 0 to list.length) {...}` loops, possibly nested if you like.

Comment: The example code you've provided is a little too minimal I think. What type, exactly, is `verticalData`? Where are the word-start coordinates supposed be be collected/stored? Does a single character constitute a word? (e.g. 1st character in 1st and 3rd rows)

Comment: Yeah i thought providing to much code would be annoying to read. @amdelamar thank you for pointing this out. Im pretty new to scala and i thought i could yield my information only like i've shown above. It worked, thank you so much! ^^

Answer (score 3):

You most probably want to work with `zipWithIndex`. An example:

```
val text = "abc\ndef\nghi"
val lines = text.split("\n")
for ((line, rowIdx) <- lines.zipWithIndex) {
  for ((character, colIdx) <- line.zipWithIndex) {
    println(character + " at " + (rowIdx, colIdx))
  }
}
```

Output:

```
a at (0,0)
b at (0,1)
c at (0,2)
d at (1,0)
e at (1,1)
f at (1,2)
g at (2,0)
h at (2,1)
i at (2,2)
```

Comment: Do you need a nested for expression? or can you do this with one?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach You could of course also write `for ((xs, r) <- lines.zWI; (x, c) <- xs.zWI) doSth`, but I decided to write out two separate loops, because there were two separate `for`s in OP's question.